# Parallelize Nested For Loops in R

Tags: loops, foreach, parallel-processing, future

I have looked at threads on parallelization and help documents on several packages. But have not been able to parallelize my calculations.

I am using RStudio on Windows that limits some of the options for the packages but this is what I have to work with.

I tried Future, package as well but no success. Here is the code I am now trying the with foreach code below. I have two For Loops so a total of 120,000 calculations. I tried this code with smaller loops (about 1000) to see if it works, but I was surprised to see that all my cores are occupied rather than 24 out of 32 cores that I specified in the code below. In addition, it seems to take much longer than expected to complete the parallel operations (still running after 10 hours). What am I missing in the following code and if there is better way to code this? Why is all 32 cores are running the task rather than 24 specified?

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

cl <- makeCluster(24, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

#set.seed(20)
#output <- 
  foreach(k=1:120000, .packages=c("magrittr", "dplyr", "pkr")) %dopar% 

for (i in 1:12000) {     # i is subject ID
  for (d in 1:10){       # d is repeats number
    nca_par[(i-1)*10+d,1]<-i
    nca_par[(i-1)*10+d,2]<-d

        nca_par[(i-1)*10+d,4]<-
      nca_dat[nca_dat$ID==i & nca_dat$DOSN==d,] %$% 
      max(AUC(TSLD, expIPRED)[,1])
    
    nca_par[(i-1)*10+d,5]<-
      nca_dat[nca_dat$ID==i & nca_dat$DOSN==d,] %$% 
      max(expIPRED)
    
    nca_par[(i-1)*10+d,6]<-
      nca_dat[nca_dat$ID==i & nca_dat$DOSN==d,] %$% 
      expIPRED[length(expIPRED)]
    
    nca_par[(i-1)*10+d,7]<-
      nca_dat[nca_dat$ID==i & nca_dat$DOSN==d,] %$% 
      (max(AUC(TSLD, expIPRED)[,1])/max(TSLD))
    
    nca_par[(i-1)*10+d,3]<-
      nca_dat[nca_dat$ID==i & nca_dat$DOSN==d,]$TRTN[1]
    
    nca_par[(i-1)*10+d,8]<-
      nca_dat[nca_dat$ID==i & nca_dat$DOSN==d,]$GRP[1]
    
    nca_par[(i-1)*10+d,9]<-
      nca_dat[nca_dat$ID==i & nca_dat$DOSN==d,]$OPTGR[1]
    
    nca_par[(i-1)*10+d,10]<-
      nca_dat[nca_dat$ID==i & nca_dat$DOSN==d,]$WTKG[1]
    
    nca_par[(i-1)*10+d,11]<-
      nca_dat[nca_dat$ID==i & nca_dat$DOSN==d,]$AGE[1]
    }}
    stopCluster(cl)
```